# Anymote Protocol on iOS/Objective-C

Tags: ios, google-tv

Are there any open-source implementations or examples of Google TV's anymote protocol for iOS?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326525/google-tv-development-environment/11358704#11358704

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not from Google. Google only open sourced the Android version of their Google TV Remote app: http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/

In a Google+ hangout one of the Google TV engineers mentioned that they are prohibited from open sourcing the iOS version of the Google TV Remote app since the Apple AppStore license agreement prohibits open sourcing apps that appear in their store.

Comment: Might have been old information on the license issue...  I'm looking into what we can open source and will keep you posted.