# google-tv development Environment

Tags: ios, google-tv

Hi I am an android developer and now I want to learn Google TV development.
I want to know how to set up development environment and emulator for execution.

I already have a android development environment using Eclipse 3.5 on ubuntu 10.10.

One more thing is it possible to develop Google TV Apps using iOS?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the main question, you might wish to download the Google TV Add-On from the Android SDK Manager., it will give you the emulator for GoogleTV HC3.1.

**There is a new C++ version of the [Pairing Protocol](http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-pairing-protocol/) and [AnyMote Protocol](http://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/) that is Open Source.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about the development environment but I know that there are issues surrounding open sourced versions of the google TV IOS products.

For example, if you were thinking of creating a google TV remote on IOS, then you might struggle to find an open source Objective-C implementation of the Google Anymote Protocol - Google are prohibited from open sourcing it because of the Apple Store licencing agreement.