# Google TV's anymote protocol for iOS?

Tags: iphone, google-tv

Are there any open-source implementations or examples of Google TV's anymote protocol for iOS?

Comment: The answer your looking for is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326525/google-tv-development-environment/11358704#11358704

Answer (score 0):

The protocol itself is open-source, so yes - there is an open-source implementation, albeit in Java:

https://code.google.com/p/anymote-protocol/

I suspect that's not what you were actually asking though...judging from your tags, it sounds as if you're after an iOS compatible implementation. Unfortunately one is not available. In the link I gave above there is a C++ codebase, but I don't think it's complete.

Of course, as the protocol itself is open there's nothing to stop you from implementing your own Objective-C/C++ version, although this would probably be fairly time consuming.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326525/google-tv-development-environment/11358704#11358704